# Ionic, ngFor how to show specific result?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Inside my ionic application, I have created a getApiData function to get the data from my Django database.

I get a series all data include of all the user inside, how can I display it only for specific user ??

Below is my json data, I have user like testuser, testproject 1 and so on.

If I only want to display data that belongs to testuser. How can I do it ??

```
[{"fields": {"date": "2018-04-16", "duration": 10, "fee": "0.06", "status": "Unpaid", "user": "testuser"}, "model": "apidb2.record1", "pk": 1}, {"fields": {"date": "2018-04-16", "duration": 30, "fee": "0.20", "status": "Unpaid", "user": "testuser"}, "model": "apidb2.record1", "pk": 2}, {"fields": {"date": "2018-04-16", "duration": 35, "fee": "0.23", "status": "Unpaid", "user": "testuser"}, "model": "apidb2.record1", "pk": 3}, {"fields": {"date": "2018-04-16", "duration": 60, "fee": "0.40", "status": "Unpaid", "user": "testuser"}, "model": "apidb2.record1", "pk": 4}, {"fields": {"date": "2018-04-17", "duration": 30, "fee": "0.20", "status": "Unpaid", "user": "testuser"}, "model": "apidb2.record1", "pk": 5}]
```

This is my coding to get data from API..

```
 getApiData_record() {
    this.restProvider.getApiData_record().then(data =>{
      this.users = data;
      var totalDuration=0;
      var totalFee = 0.00;
      var fee1 = [];

      if (this.users.fields.user = this.pushname){
        for (var i of this.users){
        fee1.push(i.fields.duration);
      }
    }
      for (var j=0; j < fee1.length; j ++){
        console.log("here", fee1[j])
        totalDuration = totalDuration + fee1[j];
      }
      totalFee = totalDuration/60 * 0.80 ;
      this.totalFee = totalFee;
      this.totalDuration = totalDuration;
      console.log("Record Here", data, totalDuration)

    })
  }
```

This is the html of how I show it.

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let user of users">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-4>
        {{user.fields.date}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4>
        {{user.fields.duration}} Minute
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-4>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; RM {{user.fields.fee}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-item>
```

Anyone know how to show only specific user like testuser only ? I received the testuser inside a global variable like this

```
 this.pushname = navParams.get('pushName');
```

This pushname is the variable I want to display. If my the pushname I received is testuser , then I only display testuser data.

Please help me !!! Thanks, I am new to ionic but this will save my life. Thanks. Appreciate !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, After sometimes I have a solution for it, I just add a simple if condition inside my .ts file..

I change this..

```
 getApiData_record() {
    this.restProvider.getApiData_record().then(data =>{
      this.users = data;
      var totalDuration=0;
      var totalFee = 0.00;
      var fee1 = [];
  if (this.users.fields.user = this.pushname){
    for (var i of this.users){
    fee1.push(i.fields.duration);
  }
}
  for (var j=0; j < fee1.length; j ++){
    console.log("here", fee1[j])
    totalDuration = totalDuration + fee1[j];
  }
  totalFee = totalDuration/60 * 0.80 ;
  this.totalFee = totalFee;
  this.totalDuration = totalDuration;
  console.log("Record Here", data, totalDuration)

})
}
```

to this

```
getApiData_record() {
    this.restProvider.getApiData_record().then(data =>{
      this.users = data;
      var totalDuration=0;
      var totalFee = 0.00;
      var fee1 = [];
      var record1 = [];
      this.newdata = record1;

        for (var i of this.users){
          if(i.fields.user == this.pushname){
            record1.push(i)
            fee1.push(i.fields.duration);
            console.log("123", fee1, i.fields.duration, i.fields.user, this.pushname, this.newdata)
          }
      }
      for (var j=0; j < fee1.length; j ++){
        console.log("here", fee1[j])
        totalDuration = totalDuration + fee1[j];
      }
      totalFee = totalDuration/60 * 0.80 ;
      this.totalFee = totalFee;
      this.totalDuration = totalDuration;
      console.log("Record Here", data, totalDuration)

    })
  }
```

I just add a if condition , if my fields.user == this.pushname (which is my ID) then I push it into a newdata array, and I ngFor in my backend to show this newdata, feel free to provide other solution, hope this helps others faced this problem.